# Storing geo-location data in an object

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I'm trying to get a users current location (using `geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`) and store it in a JavaScript object so I can use it later.

I seem to be able to store the lat and long without issue, but I can't retrieve either value individually.

Here is the code I've got:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var location = {
        data: {},
        get: function() {
            var options = {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                timeout: 5000,
                maximumAge: 0
            },
            success = function(pos) {
                var crd = pos.coords;
                location.data.latitude  = crd.latitude;
                location.data.longitude = crd.longitude;
            },
            error = function(err) {
                console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
            }
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
        }
    };
    location.get();
    console.log(location.data); // Shows data object with current lat and long values
    console.log(location.data.latitude); // Undefined
}());
```

Or a JSFiddle if that's easier: http://jsfiddle.net/akpXM/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geolocation API is asynchronous, you have to wait for the result to be returned

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var location = {
        data: {},
        get: function (callback) {
            var self = this,
            options = {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                timeout: 5000,
                maximumAge: 0
            },
            success = function (pos) {
                var crd = pos.coords;
                self.data.latitude = crd.latitude;
                self.data.longitude = crd.longitude;
                callback(self.data);
            },
            error = function (err) {
                console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
            }
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
        }
    };

    location.get(function(data) {
        // the data is only available in the callback, after the async
        // call has completed

        console.log(data); // Shows data object with current lat and long
        console.log(data.latitude); // now returns the latitude
    });
}());
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/akpXM/2/)